# Ajax POST not working without parameters in the URL

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-ajax

Google apparently is not my friend as I have tried many of the suggestions found, yet, none have worked for me.

I have 2 simple inputs as follows:

```
<form id="form">
<fieldset id="frmTest">
    <div class="form-outline">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TextBox1, new { @id = "TextBox1", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TextBox1, new { @class = "form-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TextBox2, new { @id = "TextBox2", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TextBox2, new { @class = "form-label" })
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

As well as the JS:

```
$("#SaveTest").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var data = {

    TextBox1: $('#TextBox1').val(),
    TextBox2: $('#TextBox2').val(),

};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/api/api/ConfigurationManagement/TestAjax",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.message);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> TestAjax(string TextBox1, string TextBox2)
{

    Test model = new Test();

    model.TextBox1 = TextBox1;
    model.TextBox2 = TextBox2;

    _applicationDbContext.Test.Add(model);

    try
    {
        await _applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(new UserManagerResponse { Status = "Success", Message = "Successfully added test" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(new UserManagerResponse { Status = "Failed", Message = ex.ToString() });
    }

}
```

When I click SaveTest button, I see the response as Bad Request indicating the following as if the parameters are not being passed:

```
{"errors":{"TextBox1":["The TextBox1 field is required.", "TextBox2":["The TextBox2 field is required."]}
```

On to the weird part, if I change the "url" and add the parameters at the end, it allows it to work.

```
url: "http://localhost/api/api/ConfigurationManagement/TestAjax?textBox1=" + $('#TextBox1').val() + "&TextBox2=" + $('#TextBox2').val(),
```

Though this question may appear to be a duplicate, each of our scenarios are different.  I'd like to do it WITHOUT using the parameters in the URL, I just don't understand why it is not working for me without the parameters in the URL.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your controller code

Comment: @Alexander, sorry, I knew I was forgetting something else.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action parameters are by default bound to query parameters. In order to bind parameters from post body you need to accept a `class` parameter with `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` as properties instead.

```
public class TxtModel
{
    public string TextBox1 { get; set; }
    public string TextBox2 { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveTest(TxtModel model)
```

Comment: Oh my goodness,  Since you mentioned "model", I poked around in the web project.  I was using a model from the web project (which would be empty) since I'm using the model in the controller from a shared class library.  I reverted back to using SaveTest(Test model) in my API, republished and changed my web model after adding a reference to the class library, republished the web project and would you know, it works :D Thank you so much @Alexander.